SDD drive unknown dropped from 500GB to 2GB capacity
Failed migration of OS from HDD to SSD has corrupted my SSD, I can't no longer allocated and ite showing only 2GB, can't find partition recovery or data recovery file, SSD has also tried being formatted to no avail.
I want to get my capacity back but unsure if it will be possible, any suggestions? I Have an SSD M.2 NVMe PCIe Gen3X4 512GB Model: G939E 512GB. PN: NT1FF512G2YT2E1H3A. SN: V9DW004352T.
Issue happened after OS failed migration, now showing unknown and that I only have 2GB, Tried allocating and I cant, also only shows 2GB now.


I just need to restore the capacity, you think this will be possible? dont need anything in it, I just want to gain all the capacity back and reset

If you don't mind reinstalling windows and loose all data on the drive, boot from an install media, select advanced, so it allows you to repartition your drive, remove all partitions until it says: no partition scheme, select to create one. On the empty space, click it, and then install windows. It should create all the necessary partitions and your C drive should have max capacity. Do note, if the drive is faulty, you may need to replace it, but this step you can at least test.

If you want to do more troubleshooting, and you have access to a command prompt, run diskpart and inside, do the following commands: list disk, select disk 1, list partition, list volume. Copy that information and edit your post. It'll tell us what's going on.

Silly question but has to be asked: Did you try turning it off and on again? :)

What brand is it?

Where did you get this SSD? A night market? A dropshipper? There is an epidemic of fake SSDs out there, try checking the storage using BIOS commands.
